# Showing a function is Schwartz

Tags: fourier-analysis

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104124/question-on-schwartz-function) post, for which I received a really good answer that gave a beautifull solution, yet I am still trying to understand one thing on the side that is not covered by the answer, which is the following claim:

Suppose we take a Schwartz function $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies $f(x_0) = 0$. Then, we have

\begin{equation}
g(x) = (x - x_0)^{-1}f(x) \quad \in S(\mathbb{R}) \quad (x \neq x_0)
\end{equation}

I am struggeling to come up with an idea to show this without reverting to the plain definition of a Schwartz function and trying to find the bounds on $g$. But is there another , more immediate answer? From my notes it sounds like there is, but there are no immediate steps.

The answer in the post that I linked this one to actually constructs g specifically, however in my notes the claim is made without any reference to a construction so I am guessing that I miss something here with regards to the properties of g that are imposed on it simply by the equation above...
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You want to define $g(x_0) = f'(x_0)$ as well.

You might note that $g(x) = \int_0^1 f'(x_0 + s(x-x_0)) \ ds$;  this makes it easy to show that $g$ is $C^\infty$ and satisfies the appropriate bounds.

Comment: I am afraid I need to ask - how do I show $g$ is smooth ? Sorry for this dumb question!

Comment: $g'(x) = \int_0^1 s f''(x_0 + s(x - x_0))\ ds$.  To see this is correct, look at $\int_{x_0}^x \int_0^1 s f''(x_0 + s (t -x_0))\ ds \ dt$ and interchange the order of integration.  Repeat...

Comment: okay, thanks a lot !!